# To call two toD in apache camel spring dsl xml

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-dsl

I'm going to create one rest services in rest dsl xml. On that I have created one routes. For the route I am going to call my own microservices (this is created other project) for using toD uri. Once I get response I am going to take the values from the body (response json). After that again I am going to call other services in the same route based on the response values (we are taking one field in the response).

My question is

1. how we can take the values from the response in first service
2. And how to set headers in that respected values in first values..
3. How to call 2 services in route. Is it possible to call tod uri two times?

Sample code

```
<toD uri=http://localhost >

<log message =${body} >

(this response is going to set 2nd service query parameter value )

<toD uri=http://localhost? 1 services response values a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand your case, but here are my answers to your questions:

1) You can select any value from a JSON response with JsonPath. To use it later, you probably want to save it on the Message header

```
.setHeader("myHeader", jsonpath("$.your.json.path"))
```

2) Sorry, I don't understand this question :-)

3) Yes, you can make as many `.to()` or `.toD()` as you like

However, if you want to call REST services and you use the Camel REST component, you can profit from built-in URI templating. That means perhaps you don't need `.toD()`

For example

```
.to("rest:get:hello/{myHeader}")
```

would insert the value extracted from the JSON response above because the placeholder name is looked up in the message headers and if found replaced with the value of the corresponding message header

```
.setHeader("myHeader", jsonpath("$.your.json.path")) // assume jsonpath result is "world"
.to("rest:get:hello/{myHeader}") // URI "hello/world" is called
```